# SQL Update row with inner join with substring

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, substring

I'm trying to update the town column in the a_customer_test table based on their postcode.

The select statement works fine

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.postcodes b with(nolock)
left join  a_customer a with(nolock)
on SUBSTRING ( a.postcode,1,3) =  SUBSTRING ( b.postcode,1,3)
```

But when I apply the same logic to and update query this doesn't want to work it will run but won't update anything.

```
UPDATE
a_customer_test 
SET
a_customer_test.town = b.town
FROM dbo.postcodes b   with(nolock)
left join  a_customer a  with(nolock) 
on SUBSTRING ( b.postcode,1,3) =  SUBSTRING ( a.postcode,1,3)
```

*** Working Query ***

```
UPDATE
a_customer_test 
SET
a_customer_test.town = b.town
FROM dbo.postcodes b with(nolock) 
left join  a_customer_test a with(nolock) 
on SUBSTRING ( a.postcode,1,3) =  SUBSTRING ( b.postcode,1,3)
WHERE SUBSTRING ( b.postcode,1,3) = SUBSTRING ( a.postcode,1,3) 
AND a.postcode is not null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to update all of [town] column of a_customer_test with one single value from b.town? I think you need to join a_customer_test with something and update its column accordingly..

If you want to populate the [town] when you can find a match, then you need to specify just one value to update with. Use SELECT TOP 1 for example

```
UPDATE
a_customer_test 
SET
a_customer_test.town = 
(SELECT TOP 1 b.town
FROM dbo.postcodes b   with(nolock)
left join  a_customer a  with(nolock) 
on SUBSTRING ( b.postcode,1,3) =  SUBSTRING ( a.postcode,1,3)
WHERE a.postcode IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I only want to update the town column when the first 3 digits match that's why I've used as substring as it would be much quicker.

Comment: Can you try adding a WHERE clause?

Comment: I need to update [town] with different values depending on the match of the postcode

Comment: Then you need to join a_customer_test with a and/or b then update when there's a match between a and b

Comment: Hey, glad it works now. If my answer has helped you, could you accept it?